# Is there a way to add annotation during compilation or other phases

Tags: java, compilation, annotations, preprocessor

For example:
I want to put on fields @MyContainer and then add automatically on all such fields relevant Hibernate annotations.
I need the added annotations to be available at run time (So hibernate can find them).
Thanks,
  Avner

Comment: You want to _generate_ changes during compilation? You mean pre-compilation - like in Maven? Or you want to modify existing classes?

Comment: I need to modify the classes (add annotations which weren't there before)